# Keep raster data in original projection and just display it using a new transformation (at the poles) in R vs ArcMap

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcmap, r, convert

Desired output: Raster with original characteristics but in transformed projection using R (I.e. See second paragraph [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/persist-a-transformation-to-a-raster-dataset-without-rectifying-it.htm).). NB, I need to do this for 100s of different rasters.

You can achieve this in ArcMap for a single raster doing the following. 1. Load original raster. 2. Right-click background of data frame and change coordinate system to new desired coordinate system (see figure below). Panel on the left shows original raster with cell dimensions (1 deg long by 2 deg lat). Panel on the right shows desired output, where the overall map projection has been updated and cell dimensions of raster have been preserved.

[image: Desired transformation of raster]

To achieve this in R, all roads point me toward using the function: [projectRaster](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-7/topics/projectRaster).

Where I have specified the following (r_toconvert = the raster I wish to convert; Shp_with_desired_projection = the shapefile with my desired projection):

`r.new <-  projectRaster(r_toconvert, crs=CRS(projection(Shp_with_desired_projection)), method = "bilinear")`

Note: my original raster is in projection:

`+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0`

And the desired projection for display purposes I'd like to be:

`+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0`

However, when using projectRaster I produce rasters that do not preserve the same characteristics as my original raster (plotted in ArcMap for ease of exploration).

What I would like to achieve:

[image: Desired output zoomed in]

But what I actually end up achieving using projectRaster and trying both methods:

[image: Actual output]

This seems to be somewhat non-trivial based on the ways rasters require re-projection ([as outlined here section 6.6](https://bookdown.org/robinlovelace/geocompr/reproj-geo-data.html#reprojecting-raster-geometries))

However, it clearly seems to be possible to preserve the original raster's characteristics (as evident above and in the ESRI webpage linked above) and plot with a new transformation.

WHAT HAVE I TRIED:

tmap package (which can also project on the fly):

`tm_shape(antarctica, is.master = T)+ # Set is.master to specify this is the master projection
  tm_borders(col="black")+
  tm_polygons(col="grey")+
  tm_shape(r_toconvert)+ # My original raster
  tm_raster("Var", palette = terrain.colors(10))`

Where the output is far from ideal:

[image: project on the fly with tmap]

The output is improved upon when using the new raster following projecRaster, and having the method set to ngb (method set to ngb does not seem to be the correct thing to do for a continuous variable though...):

`r.new <-  projectRaster(r_toconvert, crs=CRS(projection(antarctica)), method = "ngb")`

`tm_shape(antarctica, is.master = T)+ # Set is.master to specify this is the master projection
  tm_borders(col="black")+
  tm_polygons(col="grey")+
  tm_shape(r.new)+ # My original raster
  tm_raster("Var", palette = terrain.colors(10))`

[image: Output after using projectRaster]

But there still appears to be the same issue with new raster now losing characteristics of original raster (hence the jagged cell shapes above).

I've also played with some R base plot options, and looked in the SOmap package currently in development

I seek an R solution.

Comment: You can't preserve the input, unless you convert the raster to polygons - try spex::polygonize for fast conversion, but that has its own limitations feel free to contact directly

Comment: @mdsumner Thank you! I've posted the output below for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't preserve the input, unless you convert the raster to polygons - try spex::polygonize (see @mdsumner comment).

This is an effective solution for what I was trying to achieve.

```
## load library
library(spex)
## convert raster to polygon
r1.p <- polygonize(r_toconvert)
## change projection to desired projection
r1.pj <- st_transform(r1.p, crs=paste(CRS(projection(Shp_with_desired_projection))))
## write shapefile for viewing in ArcMap
st_write(r1.pj, paste0("./directory", "/", "shape_name.shp"))
```

Which allows me to plot rasters as polygons with original characteristics (borders and appearance at least) but in transformed projection using R.

Plot below from ArcMap for reference:

[image: Desired output achieved with polygons]

As opposed to what was achieved when using the projectRaster function (evident in the original post).

Undesired outputs below for reference again:

[image: Non-desired output]